# Change value of copy's scope change value of scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I don't understand why to change value of copy, change the value of the $scope :

```
    var tmpmember = $scope.registration.member;
    console.log($scope.registration.member.birth);
    tmpmember.birth=$filter('date')($scope.registration.member.birth,'yyyy-MM-dd');
    console.log(tmpmember.birth);
    console.log($scope.registration.member.birth);
```

Output :

```
Thu Mar 11 1954 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
261 1954-03-11
262 1954-03-11
```

Someone could explain to me please ?

Many thanks

Comment: you haven't made a copy of the object, you have made a second reference to the object.  This is basic JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for jour quick answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you presented, you haven't made a copy of the object.  Instead, you have created a second variable pointing to the same object instance.

Angular has a function you can use if you truly wish to have a copy rather than an additional reference, `angular.copy`. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy#!/

```js
var tmpmember = angular.copy($scope.registration.member);
console.log($scope.registration.member.birth);
tmpmember.birth = $filter('date')($scope.registration.member.birth, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
console.log(tmpmember.birth);
console.log($scope.registration.member.birth);
```

Result:

```
Thu Mar 11 1954 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
261 1954-03-11
Thu Mar 11 1954 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```